# Informal Data Update in Dictionary Array of Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift2

When I update values and keys into dictionary array, it updated the array in shuffle mode. Why did this happen? I want to update my dictionary array with values and keys in formal way one value and key after another without changing orders in that??

```
    let query = DB.query("SELECT data_en_id, en FROM data_en WHERE  en LIKE'\(query_result)%'LIMIT 50")

    for row in query
    {

       key_dict = Int("\(row ["data_en_id"]!)")!
       value_dict = "\(row ["en"]!)"

       dictArray.updateValue(value_dict, forKey:key_dict)


    }
```

Why did`t dictionary Array store my values and keys in order?

Comment: do you have an array of dictionaries or an dictionary of arrays? **a dictionary has no order**!

Comment: array of dictionary... How can I set values and keys in order?

Comment: @ZayYAeHtun can you please show your code

Comment: I do not see any array of dictionaries, `dictArray` is a plain old dictionary. My first point remains true: **a dictionary has no order**

Comment: Is there no way to store in order bro??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries are by definition unordered. As described in the Swift documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

If you absolutely **need** a data collection to be ordered then you should change your code to use an array instead as that is the only ordered collection type available you. However, you need to consider whether there is any need for the data to be ordered. As long as you have a way of setting the correct value for each key and then retrieving the correct value for any given key then the fact the data is not stored in an ordered fashion should not matter.